# How to handle connection pooling in cluster mode of nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am using MySQL and creating MySQL connection pool once and reusing in all other modules where needed.

When my code is running on single core this is working fine but when I use clustering and running app on multiple cores system, my connection pool is getting initialized multiple times [Based on number of cores].

How to fix this.

```
mysql.init(function (error) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    var server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
        logger.info('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the problem is. If you want to limit the total number of connections that are made to your database, you can provide a [connection limit](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pool-options).

Comment: I want to initialize connection pool only once in my app when it start and reuse everywhere, but on clustering mode it is getting  initialize multiple times , that is bad. @robertklep

Comment: The `cluster` module starts multiple separate processes, which means that it _needs_ to initialize a connection pool for each process (unless you use some sort of inter-process communication, which would probably defeat the whole purpose of starting a process per core). I don't necessarily see why it's bad.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal . Cluster mode means that you have a copy of your application running in each core . This process don't share memory .  Are individual process. This aren't threads .